# yahoo weather API PHP authorization

Tags: php, curl, yahoo-api, yahoo-weather-api

In yahoo developer guide is example how to retrieve some info about weather

```
    $BASE_URL = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql";
    $yql_query = 'select wind from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text="chicago, il")';
    $yql_query_url = $BASE_URL . "?q=" . urlencode($yql_query) . "&format=json";
    // Make call with cURL
    $session = curl_init($yql_query_url);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    $json = curl_exec($session);
    // Convert JSON to PHP object
     $phpObj =  json_decode($json);
    var_dump($phpObj);
```

this example has limit 2000 request per day, to increase limits I must use API client key and secret KEY.

How I can do authorization ? It's possible in `curl` or ? only by `OAuth 2.0`